# regex for getting word right before brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have various strings with different information but they all share one common characteristic: they contain the username of the requester with brackets right after it.  Something like: `"... paul [55] ..."` I am trying to write a regex that is able to extract the word right before the `[dd]`


This is what I have so far: `"/(?P<user>\w+)\s\[\d\d\]/"` but this only works if the string starts with the user, such as `"paul [55] has logged in"` but it wouldn't work in the case, `"user paul [55] has logged off"`


What am I missing?

Comment: You may need to include a snippet of the PHP code you are using to perform the matching/assign the regex.

Comment: It does match `"user paul [55] has logged off"`

Comment: That matches both `paul [55] has logged in` and `user paul [55] has logged off`

Comment: hmm I seem to have had a typo in my original source code! Yes you are right it does match. Apologies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [*positive lookahead assertion*](http://php-regex.blogspot.com/):

```
(\w+)(?=\s?\[\d\d\])
```

This expression matches one or more word characters only if it is followed by an optional space and a double-digit decimal number enclosed in square brackets.